# WooCommerce - Send new order emails at different order status

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-bookings

I have an issue that WooCommerce sends out the “New Order” / “Order Confirmation” email as soon as an order is placed.

When working with a payment provider like stripe or paypal, this leads to issues since people have the option to cancel within the payment process (for example at paypal with “Cancel and go back to store X”).

This works fine so far, the order gets set to “canceled” and nothing more happens.

But the Order Confirmation email gets still send, even though the user is not even done with the payment itself or cancels it.

Is there any solution how to send this email only at a different status – for example “Processing” or “Completed”?

I tried using [Send WooCommerce New Order email notification only for paid orders with processing status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66174751/send-woocommerce-new-order-email-notification-only-for-paid-orders-with-processi/66174752#66174752) answer code, but it didn't worked for me.

Comment: What do you mean *"but it didn't worked for me"*? Do you not receive any new order emails or do you continue to receive them before the payment is completed?

Comment: Hi Vincenzo! I still receive the emails even though the payment is not processed yet or if I abort the payment process in for example Paypal.